# regex for string in last portion should be numeric

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

TST0001-ABI-NGW-000003

the above is my string want to write a regex which allow just code having ending with 
6 digit numeric number .
please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Best solution here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Have you tried anything which did not work?

Comment: `/(?:\D|^)\d{6}$/.test(str)`

Comment: @Jack: as in my other comment, this matches 7 digits as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression matches strings that end with six digits, no less **but also no more**.

```
/(?:\D|^)\d{6}$/.test(str)
```

Test patterns:

```
'TST0001-ABI-NGW-000003'  // match
'ABC123456'  // match
'123456'     // match
'1234567'    // no match
```

Matching at least six digits at the end could be done with simply:

```
/\d{6}$/.test(str)
```

Comment: The last example still ends with 6 digits - that's all the OP specified. He didn't say 6 and only 6 digits.

Comment: @AidanEwen: That's programmer logic. In natural language, "There are two apples on the table" is not considered appropriate when there are three apples on the table. To get your interpretation, "ends in 6 or more digits" would be more appropriate. Still, I guess we won't really know what he wants until he accepts a solution :p

Comment: @AidanEwen That's where we have to guess what's needed sometimes, but sure, an easier regex could be added of course :)

Comment: @jack yes, well that's where I come in... An easier regex is something I can do - (you'd lost me with the characters :D)

Comment: @jack I think you're probably right. OP should be understood as asking for 6 and only  6. That is more natural language. Plus 1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
/\b\d{6}$/
```

Comment: This doesn't match `'a123456'`.

Comment: @Jack: Touche. Got distracted by the OP's shiny dash. You should submit your own updated solution as an answer...

Comment: It may not be clear what OP is after. But It's very clear what he asked for. He simply said the string must end in 6 digits. He didn't say only 6, and he didn't say anything other characters.

Answer (score 1):

`\d{6}$`

Does what you've specified. This matches any string which ends with 6 digits. (It doesn't check anything else)

```
'08909089089' // matches
'42LK429409'  // matches
'098908'      // matches
'AR09890'     // doesn't match
```